# Jenkins не сохраняет изменения после остановки контейнера

Tags: docker-compose, jenkins

Делаю для [jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker):

```
docker-compose up
```

Ввожу токен в веб-морде по *0.0.0.0:8080*. Останавливаю контейнер и делаю

```
docker-compose down
```

Затем ещё раз

```
docker-compose up
```

И оказывается, что мои изменения потерялись и не сохранились )=. Как быть? Как сделать докер инвариантным к `docker-compose down`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разбирался в том, как монтировать volume в Docker и создал отдельный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1038998/docker-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-volume), где разобраны несколько деталей.

Что касается jenkins, то сейчас рабочий jenkins можно найти [тут](https://github.com/Hedgehogues/jenkins-docker)

В Dockerfile, я заменил

```
ARG user=0
```

docker-compose выглядит так:

```
master:
  build: .
  environment:
    JAVA_OPTS: "-Djava.awt.headless=true"
  ports:
    - "50000:50000"
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - /home/infra/jenkins/data/:/var/jenkins_home
```