# Docker не монтирует volume

Tags: docker, jenkins

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home/ -it jenkins/jenkins:lts bin/bash
```

Если без it — тоже не монтирует. При этом, когда я захожу внутрь контейнера, оказывается, что файлики там есть. Снаружи контейнера их не обнаружено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует указать абсолютный путь. В противном случае, докер воспринимает его как часть пути внутри контейнера. Также следует указать юзера (`-u 0`). Иначе внутри контейнера оказывается недостаточно прав для работы

```
sudo docker run -u 0 -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /home/infra/jenkins/data/:/var/jenkins_home/ jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Вы можете посмотреть мой [форк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1038998/docker-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-volume)